# Display item.Paths.FullPath with Show-ListView command

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have the following script to output to a table certain fields of a selection of items

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@templateid='{BAC0709D-5606-4A86-AF67-35F1448FDBE6}']" | Show-ListView -Property ID, Name, DisplayName, "Page Title"
```

Obviously I just reference by name any fields I want to output, but what if I want to output a property, say item.Paths.FullPath? How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained here: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/commands/Show-ListView.html#example-2

You can use `@{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath} }` in the list of properties where you specify a label for the column and reference the item using `Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath}`

The final query becomes

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "fast:/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@templateid='{BAC0709D-5606-4A86-AF67-35F1448FDBE6}']" | Show-ListView -Property ID, Name, DisplayName, "Page Title", @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath} }
```